# Reading in filenames from stdin c

Tags: c, stdin, fgets, strtok, stat

While this is a very basic problem that should be easy to solve, I haven't been able to figure it out.  I am attempting to read in a string containing filenames broken up by whitespaces from stdin.  While it appears to read all the filenames correctly, when I use stat() on the filenames it always fails on the last file.  The files all exist and it always fails on the last one, for example if the stdin is "file.txt thisFile.txt thisFile.txt", if I ask it to print the input to stdout it will print "file.txt thisFile.txt thisFile.txt", but when I use stat() on the files it will work for all but the last file.  I believe it has something to do with the way I am reading in the files, any help is appreciated. P.S. if I end the output with a whitespace "file.txt thisFile.txt thisFile.txt " it will stat all the files with no issue.  However due to other portions of the program and other files it needs to work with via pipes the extra whitespace is not a valid format for the input.

```
char *input = 0;
char buffer[10];
size_t curMax = 0;
size_t curLen = 0;
fprintf(stderr, "accessed waiting for input\n");
while(fgets(buffer,sizeof(buffer),stdin)!=0)
{
    size_t bufLen = strlen(buffer);
    if(curLen+bufLen+1>curMax)
    {
        size_t newLen = curMax*2+1;
        if(bufLen+1>newLen)
            newLen=bufLen+1;
        char *extra = realloc(input, newLen);
        if (!extra)
            break;
        input = extra;
        curMax = newLen;
    }
    strcpy(input+curLen,buffer);
    curLen+=bufLen;
}

fprintf(stderr, "accessed input received: %s\n", input);
int i = 0;
int count = 1;
for (i = 0; i < strlen(input); i++){
    if (input[i] == ' ')
        count++;
}
char * fileNames[count];
char * pch = strtok(input, " \0FEOFfeof\n");
int j = 0;
for (j = 0; pch != NULL; j++){ //Read file names
    fileNames[j] = (char *)malloc(strlen(pch));
    strncpy(fileNames[j],pch, strlen(pch));
    pch = strtok(NULL, " \0FEOFfeof\n");
}
```

Comment: Check for a trailing newline or other non-printable character.

Comment: sorry I should have mentioned, there appears to be a trailing "\n@" after the last filename but when I attempted to copy strlen -1 it just changes the characters and it continues to change when I decrement strlen further until parts of the filename are removed @RetiredNinja

Comment: Because copying with `strlen() - 1` is not copying the `nul` terminator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fgets()` leaves the `'\n'` at the end of the read string.

So you just need to remove it, an example would be

```
while (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin) != NULL)
 {
    size_t length
    length = strlen(buffer);
    if (buffer[length - 1] == '\n')
        buffer[length - 1] = '\0';
    ...
 }
```

Comment: shouldn't strtok take care of that as '\n' is listed as a token? @iharob

Comment: That fixed the problem but I'm not sure why strtok didn't take care of it, thank you though @iharob

Comment: @CSjunkie it would make the code less clear and harder to read so why to do that?

Comment: @CSjunkie also you should not cast `malloc()` it's not needed.

Comment: I was using malloc() to avoid reading beyond the end of the input.  Since your correction I have removed it.

Comment: this kind of check for a trailing newline will fail on certain OSs that use a multibyte newline, For instance Windows and Dos

Comment: @user3629249 No it will not fail because the standard functions handle this aotumatically.

Answer (score 3):

After accept answer

The `"\0"` (an octal escape sequence) in `" \0FEOFfeof\n"` results in a truncated pattern

```
char * pch = strtok(input, " \0FEOFfeof\n");
// same as 
char * pch = strtok(input, " ");
```

Recommend some variation of

```
char * pch = strtok(input, " \n\r\t\v\f");
```

Comment: I didn't see that, that's exactly why `strtok()` isn't working and `feof` and `EOF` there? @CSJunkie `EOF` is not a character, it's a value that is returned by some functions that operate on streams when the internal pointer has reached the end of the file.

Comment: Thanks, I am not quite used to strtok and in my confusion tried to place as many non-visible terminal characters that I could think of.

Answer (score 1):

There a many problems with your code, here is a commented version:

```
char *input = 0;
```

For clarity, you should use `NULL` instead of `0` for null pointers.

```
char buffer[10];
size_t curMax = 0;
size_t curLen = 0;
fprintf(stderr, "accessed waiting for input\n");

while(fgets(buffer,sizeof(buffer),stdin)!=0)
```

Same remark as above, `!= NULL` instead of `!=0`, or you can just remove
the test completely and write: `while (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin))`, an accepted idiom in C.

```
{
    size_t bufLen = strlen(buffer);
    if(curLen+bufLen+1>curMax)
    {
        size_t newLen = curMax*2+1;
        if(bufLen+1>newLen)
            newLen=bufLen+1;
```

You test fails to allocate enough memory in some cases: if the first
line has 1 byte, a buffer of 2 bytes is allocated and `curMax` is set to
`2`.  If the second line then has 4 bytes, `input` will be reallocated to
5 bytes, 1 byte too short to accomodate 1+4+1 bytes of contents plus the trailing `'\0'`.
You should change the test to `if(curLen+bufLen+1>newLen) newLen=curLen+bufLen+1;`

```
        char *extra = realloc(input, newLen);
        if (!extra)
            break;
        input = extra;
        curMax = newLen;
    }
    strcpy(input+curLen,buffer);
    curLen+=bufLen;
}

fprintf(stderr, "accessed input received: %s\n", input);
int i = 0;
int count = 1;
for (i = 0; i < strlen(input); i++){
```

Do not recompute strlen(input) for each iteration of the loop!  Do not
rely on the compiler cleverness to optimize this code, in many cases, it
won't.

```
    if (input[i] == ' ')
        count++;
}
char * fileNames[count];
char * pch = strtok(input, " \0FEOFfeof\n");
```

As chux pointed out, the empedded `\0` in the pattern actually ends it.
Furthermore, you cannot test for `EOF` this way. `EOF` is a special value
returned by `getc` to indicate failure to read a character from the
stream, is is not an actual character that can be stored in a string.
If you change the pattern to handle other spacing characters, you
must also change the loop that counts the number of filenames
accordingly.

```
int j = 0;
for (j = 0; pch != NULL; j++){ //Read file names
    fileNames[j] = (char *)malloc(strlen(pch));
```

Allocating exactly `strlen(pch)` is a classic bug.  You need to allocate at
least one extra byte to store the `'\0'` at the end of the string.  If
`strdup` is available on your system, it will do just what you want.  I
don't understand why this useful BSD function never made it into the
Standard.

```
    strncpy(fileNames[j],pch, strlen(pch));
```

*DO NOT USE* `strncpy`.  It is very error prone and does not do what you
expect.  In this case, `memcpy` would do what you mean, copying the
filename without the ending `'\0'`.  But I suspect this is not what you
*really* mean.  You could replace these 2 lines with `fileNames[j] = strdup(pch);`

```
    pch = strtok(NULL, " \0FEOFfeof\n");
}
```

`strtok` is also error prone as it uses a static hidden variable to hold
the context. If you do more complicated things between calls to
`strtok`, this context may become overridden and your code will exhibit
strange behaviour, you may lose a long time on bugs like this.  Use
`strtok_r` or `strsep` if available on your system.

Regarding `strdup`: if it is not available, define it yourself:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *strdup(const char *ptr) {
    char *newptr;
    if ((newptr = malloc(strlen(ptr) + 1)) != NULL) {
        strcpy(newptr, ptr);
    }
    return newptr;
}
```